# Issue with Blowfish encryption using kccOptionECBMode and kccOptionPKCS7padding on ios 6

Tags: iphone, ios, encryption, ios6

I am facing problem with BlowFish encryption iOS 6. 
The funny part is the code is working perfectly fine on iOS 7. 
Here is what happens, when i execute CCCrypt function i get return value as kccSuccess , and dataOutMoved value exactly as expected. But on iOS 6 surprisingly the encrypted string contains some in between bytes as 0x00. 
I have been looking on the web a lot , couldn't find any difference between implementation of CCCrypt on ios6 and 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the answer i got from the developer forum 
It is a bug in the older system(i.e. 6.1.) which has been fixed in ios 7 .

So cant help it. 
One has to write his own algorithm to support ios 6.1.